# How to use Hibernate criteria aliasses in proiections?

Tags: hibernate, alias, projection

I have following code:

```
Criteria c = getMySession()
            .createCriteria(Company.class, "company")
            .createAlias("company.employees", "employee")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("company.name", companyName))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("employee.workingHours", companyName))
            .setFirstResult(firstResult)
            .setMaxResults(maxResults)
            .setProjection(Property.forName("employee"))
            ;
```

A Company has a list of Employee entity

If I use

```
.setProjection(Property.forName("employee.name"))
```

the result is a list of Strings of the employees' names.

If I use

```
.setProjection(Property.forName("employee"))
```

I'm expecting a list of Employee entities.
What I am getting is an error saing that "employee" is not a property of Company. How can I retrieve a list of Employee objects ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need Employee then build the query to return Employee initially.

```
        Criteria c = getMySession()
        .createCriteria(Employee.class, "employee")
        .createAlias("employee.company", "company")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("company.name", companyName))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("employee.workingHours", companyName))
        .setFirstResult(firstResult)
        .setMaxResults(maxResults)
        ;
```

Comment: but I don't have company property so the employee.company will not work

Comment: You can try .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class))

Comment: :) it also doesn't work. The projected fields in SELECT are all of teh Company, of the table relation company_employee and of the Employee. the Transformer cannot work because it will try to set the fields of the company to Employee class ..